# Java RSA Implementation: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I know that this question has been asked before, and I wouldn't ask again if I didn't understand what I've read - I'm implement a straightforward demo of the RSA algorithm - encrypt a message, decrypt and print the output, but the console shows the BadPaddingException thrown in the code:

Here's the code and the console output:

**Code**

```
public class RSA {
public static void main (String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);   // 1024 or 2048
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    Cipher cipher = generateCipher();
    String data = "abcdefghijklmnop\0\0\0";

    System.out.println("Plaintext: " + data);
    byte[] ciphertext = rsaEncrypt(data.getBytes(), publicKey, cipher);
    System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + ciphertext);
    byte[] plaintext = rsaDecrypt(data.getBytes(), privateKey, cipher);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Plaintext: " + plaintext);
}

public static Cipher generateCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    return cipher;
}

public static byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] data, Key publicKey, Cipher cipher) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
      byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
      return cipherData;
}

public static byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] data, Key privateKey, Cipher cipher) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
      byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data); // error line: at learning.RSA.rsaDecrypt(RSA.java:43)

      return cipherData;
}
}
```

**Console**

```
Plaintext: abcdefghijklmnop
Ciphertext: [B@346cd0f9
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:329)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:272)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
at learning.RSA.rsaDecrypt(RSA.java:43)
at learning.RSA.main(RSA.java:26)
```

Again, not asking for a solution, but would appreciate an explanation of the concept padding -  if you have any good resources with sample code for implementing RSA, I'd love those recommendations too.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
    byte[] plaintext = rsaDecrypt(data.getBytes(), privateKey, cipher);
```

should be

```
    byte[] plaintext = rsaDecrypt(ciphertext, privateKey, cipher);
```